# SSRS - Conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. - When converting to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: sql, datetime, reporting-services

I am running a query in SSRS which defaults the date picker date format to DD/MM/YYYY. However the dates in the actual database are in YYYY-MM-DD format. I have tried to convert these dates as below but I am getting the message "Conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value".

```
Col1 BETWEEN convert(varchar, '22/10/2013 00:00:00', 120) AND convert(varchar, '22/10/2013 23:59:59', 120)
```

I'm having some trouble working out why that error is triggering. Ie. 22/10/2013 is a valid date format so I was thinking it should convert into 2013-10-2013 easily enough?

But I guess I'm missing something!

Comment: Three questions: is the database column varchar or datetime? is the parameter properly typed as a Date? does your query work against the database directly (e.g. in SQL Management Studio)?

Comment: It doesnt work in SSMS either - it throws the same error. The column is "datetime" and the parameter in SSRS is "Date/Time"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime` values do not have a format - you apply a format when you *display* them.  You should just be able to set the parameter to a `DateTime` type and just pass it into the query without any string conversion.

Comment: Ah yes, that pretty much nails it. I went wrong by initially declaring those parameters as strings. Ie.  '@StartDate'  instead of just @StartDate. When I got the conversion error message I wrongly started to try and convert the date when all I infact needed to do was remove the quotations!

Comment: Well, that's the room problem - it was trying to convert the _literal string_ `"@StartDate"` to a date.  Parameter substitution does not just do a string replace, so you can't put parameter values in strings like that.